# Force Close Call Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am implementing a call intent in my android application. However, every time I click on the button, the application suffers force close. I have added `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` to my manifest. Also, the email button is working fine.

I am fetching the number from a mysql database using the following code:

```
phonenumber = json_data.getString("phone");
```

and this is the OnClickListener for the button

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String number = phonenumber;
                Intent callintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, number);
                startActivity(callintent);
            }
        });
```

Is there a problem with using the string, since the JSON data is converted to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this,

```
String number = phonenumber;
Intent callintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
startActivity(callintent);
```